# Get all the urls of site which coded by means of CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a sitemap generator controller which generates the sitemap.xml when url,lastmod,priority values are given. But how can i get the all urls on my site dynamically?
Site is built using CI.

Please Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) class to get feedback about your public controllers.  Loop your controller directory and grab the names of each file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the framework correctly you should be able to grep for "public function" in your controllers directory to get a list of all pages which would translate to a URL

Comment: But can I get it dynamically by coding?

Comment: Yes. I learned this behavior from phpcs (PHP Code Sniffer) http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php